# I keep on getting this expected identifier or '('

Tags: objective-c

I keep getting `expected identifier or '('` for the below code. I am trying to do an example for my school project. Anybody's help will be appreciated. This is the entire script.

```
  //
//  ViewController.m
//  Pocket Codez
//
//  Created by Dinesh1201 on 10/9/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Dinesh and co. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
- (IBAction)Generate:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Password;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)Generate:(id)sender {

struct label label = { .password = @"468392" };

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

The error is located at

```
struct label label = { .password = @"468392" };
```

now after the edit and is saying that variable has incomplete type 'struct label'

Comment: I don't see anything wrong.  The compiler will tell you where, so you need to tell us.  What header files are included?  Show them too.

Comment: struct label.password = @"468392"?

Comment: @Lukman Yeah that's not legal, however I think that is another question :)

Comment: Properties and methods that start with capitals? `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Password;` You might want to start reading some style guides.

Comment: @Lukman That's where I'm getting the error.

Comment: struct label.password = @"468392";

Comment: this is whr the error is

Answer (score 1):

You seem to imply it's the `struct` initialization that's the issue, however I would not have expected that error message, however the correct way to initialize one or more members of the `struct` is using:

```
struct label label = { .password = @"468392" };
```

Unless, of course, `label` is a property or instance variable of the class (the statement is useless, so I feel some information is missing necessary to answer your question completely).

Comment: now they say variable has incomplete type 'struct label'

Comment: @ChandrasekaranDinesh This is one of those questions where there are multiple issues and no single right answer.  You will need to provide much more information to answer this properly and I'm fairly sure I will give up and delete my answer pretty soon.

Comment: what kind of detail do i need to provide

Comment: The declaration of `ViewController` and `struct label`.

Answer (score 0):

Issues:

1. You haven't defined the struct and are trying to use it
2. `label.password = @"468392";`

   - seems you're trying to set an `NSString` object in a `struct`. Compiler won't allow you to do that.
   - So... in the solution below, i've declared `password` as `int`.

---

### Solution:

```
//[1] define the struct
typedef struct {
    int password;
    //...
} labelStruct;

@interface ViewController ()
{
    //[2] make struct variable
    labelStruct label;
}
//...
@end
```

---

```
- (IBAction)Generate:(id)sender
{
    //[3] apply value
    label.password = 468392;
}
```

---

Check: [Objective-C Lesson 14: Structs and Unions](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/objectivec-lesson-14-structs-and-unions/81) for more information.